# When using JButton draw border all buttons disappear

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I've been making a program with a GUI using Swing. When I use a JButton with the draw border it makes all other buttons disappear. I have made a program with just the minimal code and the buttons work perfectly fine:

```
public class ShowError {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame _GameWindow = new JFrame("Trivial Pursuit");
    _GameWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    _GameWindow.setSize(800, 650);
    _GameWindow.setResizable(false);
    _GameWindow.setVisible(true);

    JPanel _MainMenu = new JPanel();
    _MainMenu.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    _GameWindow.add(_MainMenu);

    ImageIcon[] _PlayerButtonImage = new ImageIcon[5];
    for (int i = 2; i < _PlayerButtonImage.length; i++) {
        _PlayerButtonImage[i] = new ImageIcon("Images/" + i + "PlayerButton.png");
    }
    ImageIcon _HowToPlayButtonImage = new ImageIcon("Images/HowToPlayButton.png");

    JButton[] _PlayerButton = new JButton[5];
    for (int i = 2; i < _PlayerButton.length; i++) {
        _PlayerButton[i] = new JButton(_PlayerButtonImage[i]);
        _MainMenu.add(_PlayerButton[i]);
        _PlayerButton[i].setOpaque(true);
        _PlayerButton[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(271,123));
        _PlayerButton[i].setContentAreaFilled(true);
        _PlayerButton[i].setBorderPainted(true);
        _PlayerButton[i].setFocusPainted(true);
    }

    JButton _HowToPlayButton = new JButton(_HowToPlayButtonImage);
    _MainMenu.add(_HowToPlayButton);
    _HowToPlayButton.setOpaque(true);
    _HowToPlayButton.setContentAreaFilled(true);
    _HowToPlayButton.setBorderPainted(true);
    _HowToPlayButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(271,123));
    _HowToPlayButton.setFocusPainted(true);
  }
}
```

This code works but when it's in my actual program it doesn't work.

This is from my actual program:

```
    JButton[] _PlayerButton = new JButton[5];
    for (int i = 2; i < _PlayerButton.length; i++) {
        _PlayerButton[i] = new JButton(_PlayerButtonImage[i]);
        _MainMenu.add(_PlayerButton[i]);
        _PlayerButton[i].setOpaque(true);
        _PlayerButton[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(271, 123));
        _PlayerButton[i].setContentAreaFilled(true);
        _PlayerButton[i].setBorderPainted(true);
        _PlayerButton[i].setFocusPainted(true);
    }

    JButton _HowToPlayButton = new JButton(_HowToPlayButtonImage);
    _MainMenu.add(_HowToPlayButton);
    _HowToPlayButton.setOpaque(false);
    _HowToPlayButton.setContentAreaFilled(true);
    _HowToPlayButton.setBorderPainted(false);
```

If I set the border painted to `false` everything is fine. When I set it to `true` everything disappears.

Comment: try this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html

Comment: @XtremeBaumer this actually helped a lot thank you. Instead of using `.PaintBorder` i should use for example `.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());`

Comment: glad i could help. so your problem is completely solved?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer yeah it is I just used some mouse listeners to add bevel on hover

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you asked another question yesterday, with a similar problem, and I told you to follow the [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html): `firstLetterLowerCaseVariable`, `firstLetterLowerCaseMethod()`, `FirstLetterUpperCaseClass`, `ALL_CAPS_CONSTANT`, and use them consistently, no matter if you add your underscore before the variable name (I don't like it though), but it should start with a `lowerCamelCase` to make it easier to read to you and us, as is it's really hard to read

Comment: @Frakcool yeah I did this is for a college assignment and this is the way my lecturer has asked for the work. If I do any work out side of college I'll use these naming conventions

Comment: Well, you should show your teacher the link I provided, because it's always a good idea to start learning thing right (the earlier, the better), he's probably using some conventions used years ago (probably in the C language) but for Java, the conventions are those I linked. At least while asking here, try to follow them (just a tip) :)

Comment: @Frakcool I wasn't trying to be arrogant or anything and I appreciate the tips, and yeah my teacher was a c engineer a few years ago. Programming is defiantly something I want to do as a career so I'm open to criticism.

Comment: *"I wasn't trying to be arrogant or anything"* I never said so... I just said, try to show it to your teacher so he can start teaching Java the right way, right now :) btw I'm glad you got your question solved, it's a good practice to post the code that solved it (if no one posted it yet) and [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), so other people know this question is already solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was actually a really simple fix

```
JButton[] _PlayerButton = new JButton[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < _PlayerButton.length; i++) {
        final int FinalI = i;
        _PlayerButton[i] = new JButton(_PlayerButtonImage[i]);
        _MainMenu.add(_PlayerButton[i]);
        _PlayerButton[i].setOpaque(false);
        _PlayerButton[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(271, 123));
        _PlayerButton[i].setContentAreaFilled(false);
        _PlayerButton[i].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());

        _PlayerButton[i].addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                _PlayerButton[FinalI].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
            }

            public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                _PlayerButton[FinalI].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
            }
        });
    }
```